# execute mysql query present in variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQLvariable

```
@query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO history VALUES (',1,',',50,',UTC_TIMESTAMP()');
```

I want to execute the insert statement present in the variable.

Comment: see my answer, i think it will work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must first prepare the statement using `PREPARE` and then use `EXECUTE`

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Something like:

```
SET @query = CONCAT("INSERT INTO history VALUES (",1,",",50,",UTC_TIMESTAMP()");

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: I got this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXECUTE stmt_name' at line 2

Comment: So how would you then recover the new record Id that was created by that executed query?

Answer (score 2):

```
Set @query = CONCAT("INSERT INTO history VALUES (",1,",",50,",UTC_TIMESTAMP()");
```

and then

```
PREPARE stmt_name FROM @query
```

and at last

```
EXECUTE stmt_name
```

Answer (score -2):

remove the CONCAT(), it's not doing anything except generate an error since it's trying to concatenate a string with nothing else.

Comment: It is actually concatenting 5 elements, it wont be any error => your answer is bad -> dont answer already answered questions - look at the `new` section and show your skills :)

Comment: illogical answer.